# Join two has many through associations in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join

I have two has many through associations in my application which allows me to assign maps to a user through an admin dashboard.

Here are the tables I have in my application.

**Mapgroups**

```
class Mapgroup < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :map, optional: true
  belongs_to :group, optional: true
end
```

**Usergroups**

```
class Usergroup < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
  belongs_to :group, optional: true
end
```

**Groups**

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :usergroups, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :usergroups, dependent: :destroy

  has_many :mapgroups, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :maps, through: :mapgroups, dependent: :destroy
end
```

**Users**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :groups, through: :usergroups, dependent: :destroy
end
```

I have been using this method to fetch the maps that the user has access to with this method:

```
def fetch_maps
  self.groups.flat_map { |g| g.maps }
end
```

However, according to my logs and testing, this is a very expensive way to do this. How can I join tables on an association like this to just get the maps in this method instead?

I have tried this joins query

```
def fetch_maps
  Map.joins(mapgroups: [:group, :user]).where(user: self)
end
```

But get this error

> Can't join 'Mapgroup' to association named 'user'; perhaps you
>   misspelled it?

Any ideas on how I can join these tables to produce the maps the user has access to?

This is the usergroups table in my schema file:

```
create_table "usergroups", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
  t.bigint "user_id"
  t.bigint "group_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.index ["group_id"], name: "index_usergroups_on_group_id"
  t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_usergroups_on_user_id"
end
```

**Maps model**

```
class Map < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :units, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :subaccount, optional: true
  belongs_to :term, optional: true

  has_many :mapgroups, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :groups, through: :mapgroups, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Comment: Didn;t you already ask this?https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/188834/a-method-that-shows-maps-users-are-a-part-of

Comment: Yes, however the answer in the code review is the code throwing the error above.

Answer (score 0):

Your `user.rb` will be like this

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :usergroups
   has_many :groups, through: :usergroups, dependent: :destroy
end
```

And reference the `user` with `usergroups`

and you don't need to `dependent: :destroy` use twice like

```
has_many :usergroups #=> remove this from this line , dependent: :destroy
has_many :users, through: :usergroups, dependent: :destroy
```

[`The has_many :through Association`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

Comment: Still getting the error listed above after adding the code you suggested in the user class.

Comment: You need `user_id` on `usergroups` table

Comment: I mean foreign_key

Comment: What is your map model